# Image on the first line disappear in wordpress posts, but DOES NOT disappear from second line onward

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a wordpress theme based on [Roots starter theme](http://www.rootstheme.com/) . However, I am facing a problem here. When I insert an image on the first line it does not appear, not even in the html mark-up (I checked page source to ensure that). However, when I insert the image from second line onward it shows up properly (also reflected in html mark-up as checked from page source).

I was wondering if that could be an issue with my theme or wordpress itself. I am using version 3.5.1 in the development environment.

Would highly appreciate any discussion on this.

Comment: Have you tried using the default theme? Most probably the issue is with your theme or a plugin.

Comment: No plugin installed, and I am developing this theme. Thats why I am trying to sort it out. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try to insert the image manually from the begining in HTML code.Find the path of the image that you want to insert and put it on

```
 <img src="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this issue lies with your theme. Try checking your `functions.php` file and see if there a filter which is related to `JavaScript` or `the_content`.